# Invoking method inside of an unknown struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct, function-pointers

Lets say a user creates their own struct that contains some code:

```cpp
struct NormalShader
{
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 color;

    void main()
    {
        color = normal * 127.5f + 127.f;
    }
};
```

Then the main piece of code runs and tries to simulate this struct:

```cpp
void ShaderRun()
{
    void* structData = alloca(structSize);
    LoadAttributes(structData);

    Invokemain(structData); //<- Pseudocode here that executes main() with the structs data at the 'structData' pointer
}
```

So my question is: Is it possible to manually initialize an unknown struct, and then somehow hack its member function for it to work on its own data, without directly having access to said struct.

EDIT:
To clarify: By hack, I mean to force the `main` function inside `NormalShader` to think its struct elements are `structData` and to execute its code on these elements.

Comment: Can you clarify your last paragraph? What do you mean by "*hack*"? What part of the code you shared is in question?

Comment: Just what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Im trying to reflection invoke the "main" function from the struct "NormalShader" during runtime.

Comment: There is no reflection in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `Invokemain()` take a template parameter that the caller can use to specify the structure type being passed in, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void Invokemain(T &data)
{
    data.main();
}
```

Then the caller can allocate whatever struct it needs to, eg:

```cpp
struct NormalShader
{
    vec3 normal;
    vec3 color;

    void main()
    {
        color = normal * 127.5f + 127.f;
    }
};

void ShaderRun()
{
    NormalShader data;
    ...
    Invokemain(data);
}
```

Comment: I was originally hoping I could grab the memory address of the `main()` function then manually push, call and pop the struct. However, this also works perfectly fine so thanks!